# Mustache: How to convert carriage returns to <br> tags

Tags: javascript, mustache

It's late and my eyes are tired, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

If I render with a Mustache template like this...

```
$(container).append(Mustache.render(template, { someText: someText}));
```

...and my template looks like this...

```
<div>{{someText}}</div>
```

...and someText is a long string that includes one or more carriage returns, how can I convert the carriage returns to `<br/>` tags?

At the moment, the carriage returns are left as-is, which means the markup looks nice, but the rendered text is all bunched up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To replace all carriage returns you can use:

```
someText = someText.replace(/\n/g,"<br />");
```

Comment: Thanks - this will indeed replace carriage returns, though for a more thorough solution I'd recommend using someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"<br />");

However, I've actually over-simplified the question, as the real problem is that someText is actually an attribute in a Backbone model - so I've added another question and will leave this one as reference for others.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984845/how-to-format-carriage-returns-in-a-backbone-model-in-a-mustache-template