# How to format carriage returns in a Backbone model in a Mustache template

Tags: backbone.js, mustache

I'm using Backbone models as input into Mustache templates to generate HTML.

I have a Backbone model with a number of attributes, such as name, description and id.  The description attribute can contain carriage returns, which I want to render as `<br>` tags when they're rendered in the template.

By default, Mustache simply outputs the carriage returns directly, so the markup looks tidy, but the rendered result has no breaks.

I don't particularly want to replace \n\r in the description attribute, as that property could be used elsewhere (e.g. in alt or meta tags).

The only idea I have so far is to add a duplicate description attribute that has the formatted text.

Is there nothing in Mustache that formats HTML line breaks as `<br>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mustache is very limited on purpose. If you need anything special in a Mustache template, you prepare your data in JavaScript so that Mustache's interpolation and loops can handle it. In your case, that means splitting your string on EOLs to get an array:

```
// Adjust the regex to suit your data, this one is pretty loose.
var lines = string.split(/[\r\n]+/)
                  .map(function(line) { return { line: line } });
```

and then loop over that array in Mustache:

```
{{#lines}}
    {{line}}<br>
{{/lines}}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This helped, but doesn't solve the problem of having to add an attribute to the model just to output correct HTML.  Models are supposed to be view-agnostic.

Comment: For now, I've used your suggestion to add a new attribute to the model, made up of lines, which the template can then iterate through, adding <br> tags inbetween.

Comment: But template views actually have two parts to them: the template itself and the JavaScript that drives the template. You don't need to alter the model, you need to wrap the template in a function that sets up the data for the template.

Comment: Actually I'd go one step further and say that if you're assuming that templates are used at all then you're doing it wrong. The details of how the view builds the HTML should be hidden inside the view object, no one else should know about the template or even care.

Comment: Through your perseverance you made me realise you're right - that's what perseverance is for right? :-)  I realised that I can pass an additional parameter (the lines) into the template, rather than adding an attribute to the model.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mu is too short's answer is correct.  I just want to add that the .map function isn't supported in IE8 (and older).

I ended up using a loop to achieve the same affect as we need to support IE8:

```
var descriptionArray = description.split(/[\r\n]+/);
var descriptionLines = new Array();
for (var line = 0; line < descriptionArray.length; line++) {
    descriptionLines.push({ Line: descriptionArray[line] });
}
```

Comment: As you tagged your question with backbone.js, I assume you have access to Underscore, which means you can transform what @mu wrote to `_.map(description.split(/[\r\n]+/), function() {...})`

Comment: Should that be compatible with IE8?